# Some IPTABLES rule is blocking my ssh access on port 22

Tags: ssh, vps, iptables

Some IPTABLES rule is blocking my ssh access on port 22, can you help me to discover which one it is? Also if you have some recomendation for other and new rules are welcome. Is for a VPS with a web app inside.

Rules:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:TCP - [0:0]
:UDP - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate N
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

resets TCP connections before the rule

```
-A TCP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

can accept SSH connections. The latter rule also is on a table called `TCP`, which is never referenced.

A solution would be to insert

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

above

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

.

Comment: So I just need to move them upper? Sorry, I'm new into iptables and VPS.

Comment: Thankyou very much but still ssh doesnt work(conection refused). I need a root VPS for a personal project, I booked a really cheap VPS for practice and testing for now. In some way I need to learn hehe. I cannot check today but tomorrow the HTTP access.

Comment: Is the SSH daemon running?

Comment: Yes sure, when I leave the rules as:
   *filter
   :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
   :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
   :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
   :TCP - [0:0]
   :UDP - [0:0]  COMMIT It works.

Comment: Ok, I studied more about the topic and I solved all problems. One of the main problems with the posted rules is the command --ctstate is castrated in some VPS as mine. Thanks everyone.